# Entity Framework 6: Right usage of "Custom Code First Conventions" Feature?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

My requirement is configuing the string length mapping globally, but also can use MaxLengthAttribute to configue a property specially. Here's my code:

```
public class StringLengthConvention
: IConfigurationConvention<PropertyInfo, StringPropertyConfiguration>
{
    public void Apply(
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo,
        Func<StringPropertyConfiguration> configuration)
    {
        StringAttribute[] stringAttributes = (StringAttribute[])propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(StringAttribute),true);
        if (stringAttributes.Length > 0)
        {
            configuration().MaxLength = stringAttributes [0].MaxLength;
        }
    }
}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {           
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Add<StringLengthConvention>();
    }

public class ContentInfo
{
   // ...
    [MaxLength(200)]
    [String]        
    public string TitleIntact { get; set; }
   // ...
}
```

My problem is the "MaxLength" can't work anymore. Do i need to check if the property has a MaxLengthAttribute before applying the global configuration in the StringLengthConvention.Apply()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What would work in this situation is to create a lightweight convention specifying the MaxLength property for strings.  In this situation the convention would set the max length of the property for all strings except where it was already configured by an annotation, with the fluent API, or by another convention.

In your OnModelCreate method add the following code to set your default MaxLength:

```
modelBuilder.Properties<string>()
            .Configure(c => c.HasMaxLength(DefaultStringLength));
```

there is a walkthough of conventions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819164.aspx
make sure to take a look at the "Further Examples" at the bottom of the page

Comment: Thank you very much, I've solved my problem. Lightweight Convention is better in this case. By the way, i find the "Futher Examples" in  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819164.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819164.aspx) use a GetCustomAttributes<IsUnicode>() generic overload, does the .NET Framework implement this itself now ?

Comment: @RongieZeng Yes, the [CustomAttributeExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.customattributeextensions.aspx) class was added in .NET 4.5

Comment: @RongieZeng Also check out the post on [Evolving the Reflection API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/08/28/evolving-the-reflection-api.aspx) if you're interested in other recent reflection-related changes.